# HTTP Post Request from iOS to Django URL

Tags: iphone, ios, django, http

Essentially this seems to be working however on the server side of things, the Query Dict looks something like this.

POST: QueryDict: {u'Contestant1 John Doe Contestant2 Jane Doe ': [u'']}

which is storing all my values as keys with no values in the Dictionary. Clearly this is a rookie mistake which I'm guessing is on the iOS side of things,  so any help would be appreciated. The code is as follows:

```
    NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL HERE"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest
                                     requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                     queryString]
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Contestant1 %@ ",contestant1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Contestant2 %@ ",contestant2] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:body];
    NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (con) {
        NSLog(@"success!");
    } else { 
        //something bad happened
    }
```

**EDIT:**  The solution to my problem.

```
    NSDictionary *postDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:contestant1, @"contestant1",
                              contestant2, @"contestant2", nil];

    NSError *error=nil;

    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];


    [theRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

Comment: What you are doing here, is simply creating a POST data by appending strings. This is what the server receives. You haven't defined "query parameters". What does the API define how you should pass parameters? In the URL? As multipart/form-data? As "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", as JSON?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about that but I was unsure as to how to define the query parameters. I think JSON would be ideal in this case.

Comment: I think I found a solution to this problem. In my NSData, I used the NSJsonSerialization and now the parameters are neatly received in the form a dictionary with the right key-value pairs.

Comment: Great!  I wholeheartedly hoped you don't need that ancient, ambiguous, confusing, error prone, and constantly changing URL percent encoded parameter quatsch.  ;)

Comment: I really don't :p Thank you!

Comment: Fine, just one thing: You really *should* set an appropriate Content-Type header when you are sending JSON. In case of JSON, this is `Content-Type: application/json`. Optionally, add the character encoding, e.g.: `Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8`.  (and pretty printing isn't really necessary, ;)  )